# npm-time throws "Unknown Timezone" error when passing a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

I have following code to update my timezone to get time for same in node.js app.

```js
var time = require('time');
var timestamp = new time.Date();
timestamp.setTimezone("Australia/Sydney");
```

***Randomly*** it throws errors like the following:

```
        throw message;
              ^
Error: Unknown Timezone: 'Australia/Sydney'
    at Function.tzset (/var/www/html/ventfeed/node_modules/time/index.js:149:15)
    at Date.setTimezone (/var/www/html/ventfeed/node_modules/time/index.js:251:18)
```

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Can you tell which time zone data version you're using? (I don't know where you'd find this, offhand...)

Comment: Allow the debugger on node-time and show us the results.

Comment: A possible race condition, exhibiting similar traits to this problem, is under discussion at https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-time/issues/64